# Clarification on "shuffled back into deck" for double-sided cards

Tags: eldritch-horror

The reference guide states for Double-Sided Cards that

> When a double-sided card is discarded, it is immediately shuffled back into its respective deck.

The phrase "shuffled back into deck" is never elaborated on and I couldn't find any discussion on this related to Eldritch Horror.

The mechanic "shuffled back into deck" can mean two things

- insert the card at a random location in the deck
- add the card to the deck then shuffle the deck. This would also trigger the rule "another player cuts the deck"

The only explanation of this mechanic I could find is for HearthStone.

> **Shuffle into deck** effects place cards into a player's deck, with its placement randomly determined. While not stated in card text, the randomness of the card's placement is achieved through subsequently shuffling the entire deck.
>
> https://hearthstone.fandom.com/wiki/Shuffle_into_deck

This would suggest that the deck should be shuffled when a player discards a double-sided card

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Eldritch Horror page on the [Fantasy Flight websit](https://www.fantasyflightgames.com/en/products/eldritch-horror/)e has all the rules and reference guide PDFs for free. If we look at page 5 of the [reference guide](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/filer_public/39/c1/39c182c1-6b0d-46c4-b5eb-dd6886b4c798/eh01_reference_guide1.pdf) on Discarding it says:

> Double-sided cards, such as Spells or Conditions, are immediately shuffled back into their respective decks when discarded.

This means that these Spells and Conditions are never permanently discarded from the game. Cutting the deck is not necessarily integral to the gameplay. The important thing is that whenever a card is re-added, all cards in the specific deck (including the re-added card) are randomly shuffled together so that the re-added card ends up in an unknown spot in the same deck.

Comment: so you also agree that the "shuffled back into deck" mechanic in Eldritch Horror means that the deck should be shuffled

Comment: Absolutely. It says to shuffle the deck; the entire deck gets shuffled.

Comment: The important part is that next time you gain this condition you may gain the same exact back side effect, but don't know about it. You can achieve this by whichever method is more convenient, as long as it provides enough randomization